# spark data locality on large cluster

Tags: apache-spark, executor

As spark executors are allocated when init SparkContext, when I load data after that(eg. use sc.textFile()), how can spark ensure data locality? I mean, in a large cluster with like 5000 servers, executor's location is random on the subset of all workers, and spark even didn't know what&where is my data when allocating executors. At this time, the data locality can only depend on luck? or is there any other method in spark to reallocate executors or sth.?

Comment: See [Tuning Spark: Data Locality](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/tuning.html#data-locality)

Comment: @zero323: I've seen that, but it's about how to find an executor of best data-locality, not about executors themselves. For example, I've servers numbered 0-9 and set 3 executors which finally locate on server #0,1,2. after executors started, I start to load data happened to be located on server #7,8,9, so data locality cannot be ensured. Does spark have some methods to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of thinking, I realized that the strength of spark is the ability to deal with iterative computing, and it should only read from hard disk for the first time. After that, everything can be reached in executors' memory. So executors' location at first do not affect much.